# Realistic Data Backup method for Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, backup, datastore

We are building an iOS app with Parse.com, but still can't figure out the right way to backup data efficiently.

As a premise, we have and will have a LOT of data store rows.
Say we have a class with 1million rows, assume we have it backed up, then want to bring it back to Parse, after a hazardous situation (like data loss on production).

The few solutions we have considered are the following:

1) Use external server for backup

BackUp: 
- use the REST API to constantly back up data to a remote MySQL server (we chose MySQL for customized analytics purpose, since it's way faster and easier to handle data with MySQL for us)

ImportBack:
a) - recreate JSON objects from MySQL backup and use the REST API to send back to Parse.
Say we use the batch operation which permits 50 simultaneous objects to be created with 1 query, and assume it takes 1 sec for every query, 1million data sets will take 5.5hours to transfer to Parse.

b) - recreate one JSON file from MySQL backup and use the Dashboard to import data manually. 
We just tried with 700,000 records file with this method: it took about 2 hours for the loading indicator to stop and show the number of rows in the left pane, but now it never opens in the right pane (it says "operation time out") and it's over 6hours since the upload started.

So we can't rely on 1.b, and 1.a seems to take too long to recover from a disaster (if we have 10 million records, it'll be like 55 hours = 2.2 days).

Now we are thinking about the following:

2) Constantly replicate data to another app

Create the following in Parse:
- Production App: A
- Replication App: B
So while A is in production, every single query will be duplicated to B (using background job constantly).
The downside is of course that it'll eat up the burst limit of A as it'll simply double the amount of query. So not ideal thinking of scaling up.

What we want is something like AWS RDS which gives an option to automatically backup daily.
I wonder how this could be difficult for Parse since it's based on AWS infra.

Please let me know if you have any idea on this, will be happy to share know-hows.

P.S.:

We’ve noticed an important flaw in the above 2) idea.

If we replicate using REST API, all the objectIds of all Classes will be changed, so every 1to1 or 1toMany relations will be broken.

So we think about putting a uuid for every object class.

Is there any problem about this method?
One thing we want to achieve is 
query.include(“ObjectName”) 
( or in Obj-C “includeKey”), 
but I suppose that won’t be possible if we don’t base our app logic on objectId.

Looking for a work around for this issue;
but will uuid-based management be functional under Parse’s Datastore logic?

Answer (score 5):

Parse has **never** lost production data.  While we don't *currently* offer automated backups, you can request one any time you like, and we're working on making all of this even nicer.  Additionally, it's easier in most cases to import the JSON export file through the data browser rather than using the REST batch.

Comment: The fact that you've never lost data doesn't mean you won't ever lose data.

Comment: We do backups too, incase that ever does happen.  It wouldn't be on you, to restore in that instance (but it is still good to keep backups, even if only for other purposes, like loading/working with the data elsewhere.)

Comment: hi Fosco, thanks for your follow up. Please clarify the following: in case we lose our data on Parse DataStore (by human errors or hacker attacks or any other reason), could we, for instance, email/call you and ask for immediate recovery from your backups?  How often do you do backup on DataStore (how old would that recovered Data set be?).  If we don't know about these, I don't think it's something developers can rely on, so please be more clear about details.

Comment: No, we don't currently restore on-demand or to correct developer/app mistakes.. only in the unlikely scenario that Parse loses data.  Not specifically sure on the frequency but would imagine it's more than daily.

Comment: Thanks Fosco. I appreciate you take the time to answer this question. I'd appreciate more if you can be more precise on the frequency of backup (could you double check with the people in charge?).  And please bare in mind that this on-demand restore function would be a VERY BIG plus for anyone anticipating to use Parse for production. So I'll impatiently wait till it's implemented...

Comment: As a developer of an app, this is a BIG gap. Users should be able to get a data backup. Maybe limit the # of backup instances. Pay more to get more backups.

Comment: In an otherwise amazing user-management system (Parse), it's a VERY serious shortcoming that no meaningful way to restore a corrupted user database is given. Even if Parse doesn't lose my user data, it's entirely likely that as a developer I will screw it up. Right now, I'm completely flying without a net when I make changes to my user data management code.
The JSON import method is not realistic. At least so far as I can tell there's no way to reconnect relationships that are keyed on the user data (restoring the dumps in the naive way doesn't seem to).

Comment: The fact that Parse still does not offer a full-fledged backup/restore solution is terrifying, and doesn't inspire confidence at all in the ability to scale for large applications. Given this state of things, who in their right mind would base an application on Parse, if they hoped to reach millions of users? The lack of a clear answer to this question, even from Parse staff, is equally terrifying. I have placed a bounty on this question in case there exists an answer that has not yet surfaced.

Comment: Is there still no full backup/restore option?

Comment: Coming soon? This has been the same story for years now. It's absolutely unthinkable that there is still no way to automate backups of your parse data.

Comment: It's not all that unthinkable when you have 600,000 apps.. but seriously, in about a week, there'll be something new.

Answer (score 5):

I can confirm that today, Parse did lost my data. Or at least it appeared to be so.

After several errors where detected on multiple apps (agreed by Parse Status twitter account), we could not retrieve data for an app, without any error.

It was because an entire column of one of our class (type pointer) disappeared and data was not present anymore in the dashboard.

We are using this pointer column to filter / retrieve data, so the returned queries and collections were empty.

So we decided to recreate the column manually. By chance, recreating the column, with the same name and type, solved the issue and the data was still there... I can't explain it but I really thought, and the app reacted as if, data were lost.

So an automated backup and restore option is mandatory, it is not an option.

Comment: thanks for sharing your experience, that's a very valuable anecdote for all Parse users. Do you know whether Parse is going to implement automated backup and restore option, even for Enterprise?

Comment: To be fair, your initial statement that Parse lost your data is completely contradicted by the outcome of your story. Data isn't magical, so the data coming back shows that it was there all along. It does seem that there was a glitch which caused the column to be hidden, but not that the data was lost. Which isn't to argue about data backup, it's just that you didn't actually experience data "loss".

Comment: Hello, as I said "app reacted as if data were lost". I was happy to gind it back. But this glitch shows that bugs are possible and, if bug are possible, backups might be required to recover from data loss, or juste to be able to migrate or sync the data.

Comment: Actually should it have already happened or not, backups should be possible for any app or server. A human error, natural disaster or hardware failure is always possible.

Answer (score 2):

On December 2015 parse.com released a new dashboard with an improved export feature. 
Just select your app, click on "App Settings" -> "General" -> "Export app data". Parse generates a json-file for every class in your app and sends an email to you, if the export-progress is done.

[image: parse export]

---

UPDATE:

Sad but true, parse.com is winding down: http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/

Comment: Still a manual process though. So unless you remember to do this every day you could run into issues. The only other option is using the JSON API to implement backup functionality yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue of backing up parse server data. As parse server is using mongodb that is why backing up data is not an issue I have just done a simple thing. downloaded the mongodb backup from the server. And then restored it using

`mongorestore /path-to-mongodump` (extracted files)

As parse has been turned to open source.Therefore we can adopt this technique.

Answer (score 0):

For accidental deletes, writing a cloud function 'beforedelete' to backup the current row to another class would work.

For regular backups, manual export of changed records (use filter) will be useful. For recovery  this requires you to write scripts / use import option (not so sure) in data browser.  You could also write a cloud function replicate data on your backup server (haven't tried this yet).

However there are some limitations to cloud code that you should consider before venturing into it:
https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-resource